# How to distinguish click() and dblcick() for a DIV element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

If I subscribe `dblclick()` and `click()` for a DIV element and make double click by mouse on the DIV, the `click()` handler calls first before `dblclick()` is called. How to avoid handling `click()` before the `dblclick()`?

UPDATE:
The question has already asked before [Prevent click event from firing when dblclick event fires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880608/prevent-click-event-from-firing-when-dblclick-event-fires). But here are good answers too.

Comment: Not only due to this problem it usually is bad GUI design to have both a click and double-click on the same element, unless you want the click action also happen when double clicked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent click event from firing when dblclick event fires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880608/prevent-click-event-from-firing-when-dblclick-event-fires)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Probably not the best way to do it:**  You could set a timeout in the click handler function and clear the timeout in the doubleclick handler function.

The timeout could call a function that will impliment what you *really* want to happen onClick and that way you can have your dblclick() function handle what happens when the users double clicks.

Comment: Agreed, this is the only way to do this.  OP should note that the jQuery docs mention that it's inadvisable to bind click and dblclick handlers to a single element. http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/

Answer (score 3):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/DAgyC/
It implements an timeout after the first click, if there is a double-click, the first click is ignored.