# Polymer ondblclick not working

Tags: polymer

I am trying to use ondblclick inside polymer element, but I cannot get it to work.

I know that I can just use `ondblclick="someFunction()"` but I need to access double clicked element model, something like on-tap event:

```
event.target.templateInstance.model.myModel;
```

```html
<script src="http://www.polymer-project.org/platform.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.polymer-project.org/polymer.js"></script>


<polymer-element name="dblclick-test">
  <template>
    <button on-dblclick="{{btnDblClick}}" on-tap="{{btnTap}}">{{btnText}}</button>
  </template>
  <script>
    
    Polymer({
      btnText: 'double click me',
      btnDblClick: function(event) {
        // in real code I need to use
        // event.target.templateInstance.model
        // just like on-tap's event param
        
        this.btnText = 'Hi, u dbl clicked me !!!!!!';
      },
      btnTap: function(event) {
        this.btnText = 'Hi, u clicked me !';
      }
    })
  </script>
</polymer-element>

<dblclick-test></dblclick-test>
```

Is there any polymeric way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First**

I was missing the [declarative event mapping](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#declarative-event-mapping) by using `ondbleclick` instead of `on-dblclick`, thanks to [ebidel edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26405937/revisions) to my question.

Even though the above example won't work.

**Second**

To solve the conflict between `on-tap` and `on-dblclick`, I used something like the following in my code:

```html
<script src="http://www.polymer-project.org/platform.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.polymer-project.org/polymer.js"></script>

<polymer-element name="dblclick-test">
  <template>
    <button on-tap="{{btnTap}}">{{btnText}}</button>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      btnText: 'double click me',
      btnDblClick: function(event) {
        this.btnText = 'Hi, u dbl clicked me !!!!!!';
      },
      btnTap: function(event) {
        if (this.tappedOneTime) {
          this.btnDblClick();
          this.tappedOneTime = false;
        } else {
          this.btnText = 'Hi, u clicked me !';
        }

        this.tappedOneTime = true;
        // reset flag after 800ms
        this.async(function() {
          this.tappedOneTime = false;
        }, null, 800);
      }
    })
  </script>
</polymer-element>

<dblclick-test></dblclick-test>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume `tap` is also fired on `dblclick` this makes it difficult. 
My (and other answers) to this question [Distinguish between onClick and onDoubleClick on same element to perform different actions in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24707911) show possible solutions.

Comment: The problem is `on-dblclick` is never being called, you may run the code snippet above ...

Answer (score 0):

Don't use on-tap and on-dblclick together, if you need both behaviors use on-click instead on-tap.

```
<my-elem on-click="clicked" on-dblclick="dblclicked">
```