# double click() HTML DOM method

Tags: javascript

I'm working on **a chrome extension** and I'm curious how to double click DOM

When I want to just 1 click I use this function

```
document.getElementById('foo').click();
```

But some elements on a website needs a double click to be triggered

So Is there any method to do that with javascript?

Comment: [dblclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/dblclick)?

Comment: Why don't you do a google search before posting a question on Stackoverflow?

Comment: @bhspencer I did and I didn't find an answer that worked for me

Comment: really the MDN reference didn't work for you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/dblclick or perhaps all the other SO questions on this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497073/how-to-differentiate-single-click-event-and-double-click-event

Comment: @bhspencer why you so aggressive :)

Comment: @Jim because SO is increasing full of very low quality and duplicate questions. The very least a user should do when posting a question is search SO to see if it has been asked before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this

```
var event = new MouseEvent('dblclick', {
'view': window,
'bubbles': true,
'cancelable': true  });
document.getElementById("foo").dispatchEvent(event);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('foo').dblclick();
```

check [.dblcick()](https://api.jquery.com/dblclick/)

If that doesn't work then use dispatchEvent() to simulate something similar.

```
 var target = document.getElementById('foo');
 var dblClickEvent= document.createEvent('MouseEvents'); 
 dblClickEvent.initEvent ('dblclick', true, true); 
 targLink.dispatchEvent (dblClickEvent);
```

Comment: I get this error "Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).dblclick is not a function"

Comment: what browser are you using? dblclick is not available on all browsers?

Comment: @bhspencer Google Chrome

Comment: try this:
var targLink    = document.getElementById ("something");
var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
clickEvent.initEvent ('dblclick', true, true);
targLink.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);

Comment: @Identity1 that worked thank you, edit you answer with the new code to help other pepole