# Fullcalendar: detect click in week or day view

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, frontend

I'm currently detecting double click events in month view. This works well:

```
dayRender: (date, element) => {
  element.bind('dblclick', ...)
}
```

What I'm looking for is a way to do the same when the user is in day view or week view. I want to be able to detect a click event, and get the date and time they clicked on (note that time is relevant in day/week view, but not month view).

Any ideas?

Comment: What I did is create a doubleclick listener on the .dayClick option, because there you have all the info you need. [Here is the code to create a double click for a single click listener](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26296759/1449624)

Comment: that's note enough, because i also need the time info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that finds this in the future, here's the hacky solution I came up with:

Because fullcalendar doesn't render a `<div>` per time slot (eg. a single div representing 1pm-1:30pm on 1/2/2015), and instead visually represents a single time slot as the intersection of a row and a column, we need a way to figure out the time from a given click. Day info is already attached to each column (day) DOM element in the form of a `data-date` attribute. What I did was I [forked](https://github.com/bcherny/fullcalendar) fullcalendar, and added time info to each row (time slot) with a [new `data-time` attribute](https://github.com/bcherny/fullcalendar/commit/a42291dfaa0bfe2efcc4afdb7a298e740207f0e0#diff-6e890b4abc5e3be617f56dbde8afa3eaR5761).

Then, I listened on the double click event onViewRender, figured out the elements the user clicked on, and from those was able to derive both the date and the time slot:

```
viewRender: (view, element) ->

  if view.type in ['agendaDay', 'agendaWeek']
    element.on 'dblclick', (event) ->

      els = document
        .elementsFromPoint event.pageX, event.pageY
        .filter (e) -> (e.hasAttribute 'data-date') or (e.hasAttribute 'data-time')
      date = (_.find els, (e) -> e.hasAttribute 'data-date').getAttribute 'data-date'
      time = (_.find els, (e) -> e.hasAttribute 'data-time').getAttribute 'data-time'

      return unless date and time

      startTime = moment "#{ date } #{ time }"
      endTime = (moment startTime).add 30, 'minutes' # clone + increment
```

This is a really hacky solution, and mixes all sorts of concerns. However, until fullcalendar adds support for a `timeClick` event, this works pretty well.

Hope this helps someone else!