# how to check the click is single or double in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I am trying to check whether a click on an element is a single click or a double click.

I am trying with this code.

```
var clk_ch = document.getElementById('clk');

function singleClick() {
    alert("single click");
}

function doubleClick() {
    alert("double click");
}

var clickCount = 0;

clk_ch.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert();
    clickCount++;
    if (clickCount === 1) {
        singleClickTimer = setTimeout(function() {
            clickCount = 0;
            singleClick();
        }, 400);
    } else if (clickCount === 2) {
        clearTimeout(singleClickTimer);
        clickCount = 0;
        doubleClick();
    }
}, false);
```

I am not getting any alert. Where am I going wrong? `clk` is the id of the clicked element

```
<input type="image" src="button.gif" id="clk" >
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to differentiate single click event and double click event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497073/how-to-differentiate-single-click-event-and-double-click-event)

Comment: I think the answer here is better than the one in the link.

Comment: This might help. It has a fiddle http://stackoverflow.com/a/7845282/2270492, FIDDLE:http://jsfiddle.net/KpCwN/4/

Comment: @stevenw00 the issue which was being discussed there is still replicated here.  According to me it is duplicate and will result in the same answer.

Comment: @hemal instead of anchor tag can we do it for input type which contains image?

Answer (score 4):

No need of using `setTimeout`. You can add [`dblclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/dblclick) event listener.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {

    var clk_ch = document.getElementById('clk');

    clk_ch.addEventListener('click', singleClick, false);
    clk_ch.addEventListener('dblclick', doubleClick, false);

});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/1mo1jx4r/)

In jquery:

```
$('#clk').on('click', singleClick).on('dblclick', doubleClick);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/fzv2mn2q/)

Comment: Since this is tagged as jQuery it might useful to know that they also offer it. http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/.

Comment: should i include any library to work with addEventListener()...i m not getting alert atall :(

Comment: @Alén No, you don't need any library for that.

Comment: for Click event nothing is trigering

Comment: When you double click, single click is also firing as per your jQuery code. Any workaround?

Comment: I have replied with already available answer and that is a good solution.