# Single click and Double click on the same element, not working; Javascript

Tags: javascript, code.org

I am trying to add a click function that triggers when a button is clicked. I am also trying to figure out how to add a double click function onto the same element, that triggers a different event.

```
var click = false;
onEvent("image2", "click", function(event) {
  click = true;
});
if (click === true) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    onEvent("image2", "click", function(event) {
      setScreen("safeScreen");
      console.log("double click");
    });
  }, 200);
} else {
  onEvent("image2", "dblclick", function(event) {
    setScreen("safeScreen");
    console.log("click");
  });
}
```

This code is completely wrong, but I don't know where to start/correct. What am I doing wrong? I am looking to have the single click not trigger when the user double clicks.

Comment: Not sure what your problem really is. Use Javascript addEventListeners suchas 'click' for single click and 'dblclick' for double click. Additional reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497073/how-to-differentiate-single-click-event-and-double-click-event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:**

Try passing a function clicks() to your event listener like so:

```
onEvent("image2", "click", clicks);
```

Function `clicks()` will check if there was a single or double click based on `setTimeout` function. You can adjust `setTimeout` via `timeout` variable and of course you need `clickCount` variable declared outside clicks() function.

---

**Pure js approach**

Try adding two event listeners. Less code, much cleaner. Check this working example.

```js
var selector = document.getElementById('codeorg');
selector.addEventListener('click', clicks);


// Global Scope variable we need this
var clickCount = 0;
// Our Timeout, modify it if you need
var timeout = 500;
// Copy this function and it should work
function clicks() {
  // We modify clickCount variable here to check how many clicks there was
  
      clickCount++;
      if (clickCount == 1) {
        setTimeout(function(){
          if(clickCount == 1) {
            console.log('singleClick');
            // Single click code, or invoke a function 
          } else {
            console.log('double click');
            // Double click code, or invoke a function 
          }
          clickCount = 0;
        }, timeout || 300);
      }
}



// Not important for your needs - pure JS stuff
var button = document.getElementById('button');

button.addEventListener('click', singleClick);
button.addEventListener('dblclick', doubleClick);

function singleClick() {
  //console.log('single click');
}

function doubleClick() {
  console.log('double click');
}
```

```css
#codeorg {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Double Click</h2>

<button id="button">Click me</button>


<hr><hr>


<h2>Double click or Single Click</h2>

<button id="codeorg">Click me</button>
```

Comment: For some reason the coding environment that I am using is saying: "Error: line 4: TypeError: undefined is not a function". It is giving me this error after trying to test your code in my coding environment.

Comment: I see, you are using strict mode. I've updated my answer, should be working now. I was missing `var`.

Comment: Now on line 1 it is saying "Unknown identifier: document".

Comment: The coding environment that we are required to use is weird and seems to restrict a lot functions from javascript. Are you familiar with code.org?

Comment: Never heard of it, but running this piece of code alone won't solve the problem? 
`onEvent("image2", "dblclick", function(event) {
    console.log("click");
  });`

Comment: It does not solve the problem. What I am trying to do is have an element that activates and performs an action when I click, but also have that same element activate and perform a different action when I double click. If that makes any sense.

Comment: I have read through the documentation of onEvent before though.

Comment: Yes it does, is there a playground so I can test the code?

Comment: https://studio.code.org/projects/applab/Wd2KBBM1FnnByFABb_OIIncvmfWwZxoecqy7uGdlCEI/edit

Comment: It does require an account, I can test any code given if that helps. I will link the documentation to everything that we can use.

Comment: https://docs.code.org/applab/ this is all the documentation of everything that we can use.

Comment: Do I include the first 2 lines? I get the same problem from before if I do.  "Unknown identifier: document"

Comment: I've updated the code, look at it now, you need to add `clicks()` function I prepared for you. It detecs if you clicked once or twice, based on `setTimeout()`.

Comment: @Holothrasher You don't need to pass two first lines.

Comment: Anyway you need to implement `clicks()` function. If it helped you mark this question as answered, so other people can see it.

Comment: THIS WORKS!!!! Thank you so much, I was trying to get this to work for days, and couldn't get it. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Glad I could help you :)