# How to make the second onclick() without onDBLClick

Tags: javascript, php, html, function

i don't want to use the double click function , instead i just 
want to run the below buttonOnClick() when a user click two times not single time , Help me iam new to coding

```
                <button onclick="buttonOnClick();" onmouseover="mouseOver();" onmouseout="mouseOut();">Subscribe <i id="ytb" class="fa fa-youtube-square ytb"></i></button>
                <br>


             </div>
```

function buttonOnClick()

```
{


  window.open('https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCXE6pw29K2lHS_2fB8LeU1Q?sub_confirmation=1','_blank');



  setTimeout(aTagChange, 12000);

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to differentiate single click event and double click event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497073/how-to-differentiate-single-click-event-and-double-click-event)

Comment: Why don't you want `dblclick` when you want to ignore single clicks at all?

Comment: hi cause by properller ads , it load the onpage script , which covers the whole page , so when a user click on button , without going to the target url it takes it as a Click and runs the function ,

Comment: Are you writing a GreaseMonkey/TamperMonkey userscript?

Comment: no , bro nothing like that

Comment: Why can't you overwrite the `onclick` event to do nothing and additionally add the `dblclick` listener?

Comment: quasim, the prevClick method by jack worked, but its not working from my mobile , from pc its working

Answer (score 3):

Set a variable `prevClick` then update and check it:

```
var prevClick = false;
function buttonOnClick() {
    if (prevClick) {
        window.open('https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCXE6pw29K2lHS_2fB8LeU1Q?sub_confirmation=1','_blank');
        setTimeout(aTagChange, 12000);
    } else {
        prevClick = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: the above code is working on my pc but not on mobile ??

Comment: There are no `click` events on mobile IIRC

Comment: you mean it will only work with pc not with mobile ? is there any solution to it ?

Comment: Use a mobile event

Comment: please help me in that , i don't have enough knowledge of coding

Comment: My bad - replacing `onclick` with `ontouchstart` should fix it for mobile.

Comment: dear jack , should i rewrite the whole code again u mean , one for onclick and another for ontouchstart ?

Comment: Yes, copy paste the code but change `onclick` to `ontouchstart`

Comment: hi jack its creating two buttons now i pasted this   https://pastebin.com/FqW88DQi

Comment: hi jack are you there ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ondblclick`

```js
function func(){
  console.log("double clicked");
}
```

```html
<button ondblclick="func()">Subscribe <i id="ytb" class="fa fa-youtube-square ytb"></i></button>
```

You can have a `Boolean` to check if the its clicked once or not

```js
let clicked = false;
function func(){
  if(clicked === false){
    clicked = true;
    return false;
  }
  else clicked = false;
  console.log("clicked second time");
  
}
```

```html
<button onclick="func()">Subscribe <i id="ytb" class="fa fa-youtube-square ytb"></i></button>
```

Comment: hi i don't want double click bro i just want the buttonOnClick()  to work when i click the button two times

Comment: @Nitesh Kumar I edited and added the other way check it please

Comment: thanks or the script , the prevClick method by jack worked, but its not working from my mobile , from pc its working can u help please