# how to differentiate between click and double click on the calendar appointments?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

i am using planning calendar.i have a click function on the calendar appointment and i have customized the calendar appointment with Double click.
if i double click on the appointment both click and double click function is getting triggered.how to fix this ?

```
// this is the custom Calendar Appointment code.

sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/unified/CalendarAppointment"
],
function (
  CA
) {
  "use strict";
  var CalendarAppointment = CA.extend("com..........util.CalendarAppointment", {
    metadata: {
      events: {
        "rightpress": {},
        "dblclick": {}
      }
    }
  });
  CalendarAppointment.prototype.oncontextmenu = function (ovt) {
    this.fireRightpress();
  };
  CalendarAppointment.prototype.ondblclick = function (ovt) {
    this.fireDblclick();
  };
  return CalendarAppointment;
});
```

Comment: what is triggered on the double click ?  You should also post your code here

Comment: There is similar question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497073/how-to-differentiate-single-click-event-and-double-click-event

Answer (score 0):

Use a timeout to cancel simple click in case a second click is received in a short interval

```
// this is the custom Calendar Appointment code.

sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/unified/CalendarAppointment"
],
function (
  CA
) {
  "use strict";
  var CalendarAppointment = CA.extend("com..........util.CalendarAppointment", {
    metadata: {
      events: {
        "rightpress": {},
        "dblclick": {}
      }
    }
  });
  CalendarAppointment.prototype.oncontextmenu = function (ovt) {
    clearTimeout(this._singleClickTimeout)
    var DURATION = 250;
    this._singleClickTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      this.fireRightpress();
    }, DURATION)
  };
  CalendarAppointment.prototype.ondblclick = function (ovt) {
    clearTimeout(this._singleClickTimeout)
    this.fireDblclick();
  };
  return CalendarAppointment;
});
```