# how to disable a div after double click on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div tag in my html. I want to disable it after I double click on it.

```
<div id="mydiv">
</div>


    $('#mydiv').on('click', function (event) {

        var count = parseInt($('#counter').html(), 10)
        count += 1
        $('#counter').html(count)
        $('#counter').attr("disabled", disabled)

    })
```

Comment: Where is `#counter` element?

Comment: why not use dblclick event

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to differentiate single click event and double click event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497073/how-to-differentiate-single-click-event-and-double-click-event)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dblclick event as follows - this works exactly as the click event but the counter is no longer necessary

HTML

```
<div id="myDiv" style="background:red">Has not been double clicked</div>
```

JS (JQUERY)

```
$('#myDiv').on("dblclick",function(){
  this.innerHTML = "Was double clicked";
});
```

Live example - https://playcode.io/374412?tabs=script.js,preview

Answer (score 0):

Jquery provides dblclick and unbind function.
`dblclick` function trigger when `mydiv` is double clicked by user. You can write your code in instead alert. In addition if you want to remove the `dblclick` event once it is used or clicked

```
$( "#mydiv" ).dblclick(function() {
alert("sample");
//your code will go here
  $(this).unbind();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    let clicked = 0;
    $('#mydiv').on('click', function (event) {
    clicked =clicked+1;
    if(clicked>=2){
            $('#counter').attr("disabled", disabled); 
    } 
   })
```

Comment: A double click = two clicks in low interval of time, your solution will add the `disabled`attr if user click two times in 5 min without reloading the page