# JavaScript: How prevent dblclick (Double Click) to also fire a single click event

Tags: javascript, html

I want avoid that double click also fire a single click event.

A simple solution i found is to delay the click with a timer and destroy the timer if a double click is fired.

```js
var pendingClick;

function myclick(){
   clearTimeout(pendingClick);
   pendingClick = setTimeout(function(){
      console.log('click');
   }, 500);
}

function mydblclick(){
  clearTimeout(pendingClick);
  console.log('double click');
}
```

```html
<div onclick="myclick()" ondblclick="mydblclick()">Double Click Me!</div>
```

But this solution is based on timing, if the double click is too slow (>500ms) it also fire a single click.

There is a stable solution for handle both click and double click?

Answer (score 2):

Only work with the 'onclick' function to check if it was one or two clicks and use a variable to count the number of clicks in a given time interval.

Example:

```js
var pendingClick;
var clicked = 0;
var time_dbclick = 500 // 500ms

function myclick(){
  clicked++;
  clearTimeout(pendingClick)
  if(clicked >= 2){
    mydblclick()
    clicked = 0;
  } else {
    pendingClick = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('One click!')
      clicked = 0;
    }, time_dbclick);
  }
}

function mydblclick(){
  console.log('double click');
}
```

```html
<div onclick="myclick()">Double Click Me!</div>
```

Comment: you set a timeout and clear an interval... (maybe you want clearTimeout?)

Comment: ingeneous solution

Answer (score 2):

You can get the event and cancel it with the addEventListener like this:

```js
document.getElementById('mydiv').addEventListener('click', myclick)
document.getElementById('mydiv').addEventListener('dblclick', mydblclick)

let pendingClick

function myclick() {
  clearTimeout(pendingClick);
  pendingClick = setTimeout(function (){
    console.log('click')
  }, 500);
}

function mydblclick(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  event.stopPropagation()
  clearTimeout(pendingClick)
  console.log('double click')
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">Double Click Me!</div>
```

Comment: I want  handle both click and double click

Comment: can you check your snippet, double click doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Double-clicking in itself is "based on timing", even in the standard implementation of `dblclick` / `ondblclick`. There will always be the issue of a single-click being fired if the double-click is "too slow". What is "too slow"? 300ms? 500ms? 1000ms? Your double-clicks may be only 50ms apart, while my mom's double-clicks are 1-2 seconds apart...

Comment: On a computer used only by a single person there ought to be ways to calibrate timings for such differences in user characteristics. But my mom who is 89 would first need a course on what double clicking is and when it is used. And may still not grasp it.

Comment: A question if there is any point in double clicking anymore got put on hold 10 years ago: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/18819/is-double-click-necessary-anymore

Answer (score 1):

### Custom Events instead of inline event handlers

If one prefers to use `.addEventListener` and `.removeEventListener` instead of HTML inline-eventhandlers, I would suggest another approach based on [Custom Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent). That means one would not make use of the standard implementation of "click" and "dblclick", but create own event handling for both:

```
let lastLeftClick = document.dispatchEvent(new Event("click")); 
let doubleclickLength = 300;

function leftClickHandler (e) {
  if (e.button != 0) return; // only left clicks shall be handled;

  let delaySinceLastClick = e.timeStamp - lastLeftClick.timeStamp;
  let eIsDoubleClick = delaySinceLastClick < doubleclickLength;

  if (eIsDoubleClick) {
    let doubleclickEvt = new CustomEvent("doubleclick", e);
    lastLeftClick = lastLeftClick = doubleclickEvt;
    document.dispatchEvent(doubleclickEvt);
  } else {
    let singleClickEvt = new CustomEvent("singleclick", e);
    lastLeftClick = singleClickEvt;
    document.dispatchEvent(lastLeftClick);
  }
}

// adding above click event implementation: 
document.addEventListener("click", leftClickHandler);
```

### using the new custom events:

```
document.addEventListener("singleclick", e=>console.log("single click"));
document.addEventListener("doubleclick", e=>console.log("double click"));
```