# How to customize singleclick to doubleclick? js

Tags: javascript

I need to customize single click event to double click. And it have to work if second click is clicked in 300 ms.

Comment: I think this post can help you! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497073/how-to-differentiate-single-click-event-and-double-click-event

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to differentiate single click event and double click event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497073/how-to-differentiate-single-click-event-and-double-click-event)

Comment: Here is the guidelines for posting a good question, read it over whenever you have time! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work. Basically you can save the first click, and set a timer to reset that click if no other click is there.

I'm sure there are plenty of better ways to do this, but this works:

```js
let clicked = false;
const timeout = 300;
let timer;
function onClickHandler(e) {
  console.log('click');
  document.querySelector('#result').innerText = '';
  if (timer) window.clearTimeout(timer);
  if (!clicked) {
    console.log('first time');
    clicked = true;
    timer = window.setTimeout(() => clicked = false, timeout);
  } else {
    console.log('double click');
    clicked = false;
    document.querySelector('#result').innerText = 'Double click!';
  }
}
```

```css
#result{background:red;}
```

```html
<div onclick="onClickHandler(event)">Click me twice</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Description

Here is an example using the `Timeout` built into JavaScript

### Example:

```js
// the double click time amount
const doubleClickTimeout = 300
// timer variable used to store our timeout pointer
let timer = undefined

// clear function that kills the timeout/timer and variable
let clear = () => {
  if (timer) clearTimeout(timer)
  timer = undefined
}

// starts the timeout/timer
let clickStart = () => {
  timer = setTimeout(clear, doubleClickTimeout)
}

// gets the area you want to monitor
const doubleClick = document.getElementById("doubleClick")
// set up a onclick event on the doubleClick variable that points to the doubleClick div
doubleClick.onclick = () => {
  // if timer isn't undefined then we have a double click
  if (timer) {
    console.log("double click detected")
    // call the clear function: clear the timer
    clear()
  } else {
    // call the clickStart function: start a timer
    clickStart()
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="doubleClick">this is a clickable area with custom double clicking</div>
```