# Maui: different events for single and double tapped

Tags: c#, event-handling, maui, double-click

How do I create different methods when double-tap vs. single-tap?
How to recreate:

1. Take the default "New Maui App"
2. Add the first two code blocks from this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/gestures/tap?view=net-maui-7.0
3. Then add a second function for single-tap
   The MainPage.Xaml now looks like this (truncated after image part since the rest is the same):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp2.MainPage">

    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center">

            <Image
                Source="dotnet_bot.png"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Cute dot net bot waving hi to you!"
                HeightRequest="200"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" >
                <!--******* add gesture recognizers to default app ******-->
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTapGestureRecognizerDoubleTapped"
                              NumberOfTapsRequired="2" />
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTapGestureRecognizerSingleTapped"
                              NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                <!--******** end add gesture recognizers to default app *******-->
            </Image>

            <Label
                Text="Hello, World!"
...
```

Then in MainPage.xaml.cs, I've added the two methods:

```
    void OnTapGestureRecognizerDoubleTapped(object sender, TappedEventArgs args)
    {
        CounterBtn.Text = $"Double tapped image";

    }
    void OnTapGestureRecognizerSingleTapped(object sender, TappedEventArgs args)
    {
        CounterBtn.Text = $"Single tapped image";

    }
```

Now, when you run and double-click/tap the image, it goes first to the single-tap method, then the double-tap method, then back to the single-tap method.

**What is the best way to prevent calls to the single-tap method?**

Comment: I don't think you can combine two tap gestures this way.  You could try using a single tap gesture and track if a 2nd tap is received within some time span

Answer (score 3, accepted):

based on these comments, I implemented the double-tap vs single-tap like this:

```
    bool doubleTapped;
    bool ignoreNextTap;
    void OnTapGestureRecognizerDoubleTapped(object sender, TappedEventArgs args)
    {
        doubleTapped = true;
    }
    async void OnTapGestureRecognizerSingleTapped(object sender, TappedEventArgs args)
    {
        var delay = Task.Delay(555);
        await delay;
        if (ignoreNextTap)
        {
            ignoreNextTap = false;
            return;
        }
        if (doubleTapped)
        {
            doubleTapped = false;
            ignoreNextTap = true;
            CounterBtn.Text = $"Double tapped image";
        }
        else
        {
            CounterBtn.Text = $"Single tapped image";
        }
    }
```

It works, but it sure seems hacky. Basically, what single tap method sleeps for half-of-a-second, to see if the doubleTapped flag will be raised. If it is, then it calls the code that should be executed for doubleTap ("CounterBtn.Text = $"Double tapped image";"). Otherwise, it calls the singleTap code ("CounterBtn.Text = $"Single tapped image";").
However, in order to prevent the second single click from registering, I put another Boolean for ignoreNextTap. I saw similar posts from other languages ([How to customize singleclick to doubleclick? js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65343058/how-to-customize-singleclick-to-doubleclick-js)) and the general approach is the same as this. I guess there is no other way to do this other than the Delay/Sleep approach to see if a second click happens. This will generally cut into the snappy-ness of the UI.

Answer (score 1):

For me it works as intended with a border control. One tap goes to the first method and two taps go to the second method:

```
                <Border.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" />
                <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="2" Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped_2" />
            </Border.GestureRecognizers>
```

//Code behind

```
private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, TappedEventArgs e)
    {
        //tapped once
    }

    private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped_2(object sender, TappedEventArgs e)
    {
        //tapped twice
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, the [Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.image?view=net-maui-7.0) will respond to `single taps`. So `single-tap` method would be triggered at first tap. When the `NumberOfTapsRequired` property is set to greater than one, the event handler will only be executed if the taps occur within **a set period of time**. If the second (or subsequent) taps don't occur within that period, they're effectively ignored.

So as Jason suggested, it's better to use a `single tap gesture` and track if a 2nd tap is received within some time span.

Answer (score 0):

The above options did not suit me, because the selection of the list item was incorrectly processed. Implemented a double tap through tracking the timer period (0.5 seconds).
In xaml.

```
<ListView x:Name="Target_listview" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTapped="Target_listview_ItemTapped">
```

In cs.

```
private Timer Doubleclick_timer;
private void Target_listview_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Doubleclick_timer != null) //0,5 duobleclick
    {
        Doubleclick_timer.Dispose();
        Doubleclick_timer = null;
        toast = Toast.Make("2");
        toast.Show();
    }
    else //singleclick
    {
        Doubleclick_timer = new Timer(DoubTCallBack, null, 500, 500);
    }
}

private void DoubTCallBack(object state)
{
    Doubleclick_timer.Dispose();
    Doubleclick_timer = null;
}
```