# Mapboxgl map.on('click') event disable double click zoom

Tags: javascript, angular, mapbox-gl-js

I'm using Mapboxgl in angular, and I have this code and everything is well:

```
map!: mapboxgl.Map;
loadMap()
{
   (Mapboxgl as any).accessToken = environment.mapBoxKey;
   this.map = new Mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'map-box', // container id
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
      center: [5, 51], // starting position
      zoom: 5 // starting zoom
    });
}
```

When I add 'click' event to the map, the double click zoom not working.
this is the 'click' event code:

```
this.map.on('click', (e) =>{
      if(this.marker != null){
        this.marker.remove();
      }
      //creatMarker(e.lngLat.lng, e.lngLat.lat);
    });
```

how can fix that?

Comment: I think I personally understand what you mean because I am having a similar issue. You want to do something on click but exclude a double click. Almost like a single click event. I think the way to go is to have a click event and detect when you are in a double click and if so, not do anything. I am currently trying to find out exactly. If I do, I'll post the solution.

Comment: Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497073/how-to-differentiate-single-click-event-and-double-click-event/60177326#60177326

Answer (score -1):

For double click use **dblclick** insted of **click**

Comment: this is not my question. I want to keep zoom enabled when dbclick
which it's enabled by default

Comment: You can disable default zoom: this.map.scrollZoom.disable() and enable it when you want