# How to improve javascript click / dblclick event handling

Tags: javascript

There are many questions and answers on the topic of separating 'click' and 'dblclcik' events on the same element. They usually use a timer, something like this:

```
let clicks = 0;
let clickTimer = -1;

function clickMe() {
   ++clicks;
  if (clicks === 1) {
      clickTimer = window.setTimeout(function() {
      count(false);  //perform single-click action 
      clicks = 0;    //after action performed, reset counter
    }, 200);
  }
  else {
      clearTimeout(clickTimer);    //prevent single-click action
      count(true);  //perform double-click action
      clicks = 0;   //after action performed, reset counter
  }
}
```

The trouble is the delay: 200 ms appears to be best from my trials, but then a slow dbl-click sometimes leads to two single clicks. Any bigger timeout leads to a very non-user-friendly delay before a normal click is processed.
Is there a better way?

A [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/exbuyka2/) to play with, if required.

Using the `dblclick` event doesn't work for me because it emits two `click` events first:

```js
let click = document.getElementById("click");
let result = '';


function clickMe() {
  result += "single click ";
  showResult();
}

function doubleClick() {
  result += "double click ";
   showResult();
}

function showResult() {
 click.innerHTML = result;
 setTimeout(()=> {
    result = '';
  click.innerHTML = result;
 },1500)

}
```

```html
<button onclick="clickMe()" ondblclick="doubleClick()">
  Click me
</button>

<p id="click"></p>
```

Comment: What about Promises? you can try to  utilize Promises to manage it. Execute the single-click action immediatelyl, but have it reversible. If a double-click is detected shortly after, reverse the single-click action and perform the double-click action instead.

Comment: Most modern browsers support both event handlers thus allowing the user settings to come into play properly depending on the local machine/user ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/dblclick_event and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event and then hook into them with `addEventListener("dblclick"` and `addEventListener("click"`

Comment: Related is the `event.detail` ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/detail

Comment: @GagBaghdasaryan promises look promising (!) but I struggle with coding them - could you perhaps give an example of how this might be done?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss other answers have mentioned using `event.detail` but comments on those have also suggested isues. Nevertheless I'll look into it more.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss There is an answer using `event.detail` here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497073/ but it suffers the same problem as using `dblclick`, i.e. sometimes a single click is fired before the double.

Comment: Just a random thought a day later; I once had to deal with a similar issue and wrapped the button in a div and put the click on one and the double click event handler on the other which helped work around this - depends on your circumstance and use - yours seem to be able to use that strategy given the simple code posted but your actual use may not.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I posted something very similar as answer just as you were writing your comment! See below.

Answer (score 2):

Full support on most browsers since Dec. 22, 2023.
Please enjoy the new `eventListener` [`dblclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/dblclick_event).

```js
const card = document.querySelector("aside");
card.addEventListener("dblclick", (e) => {
  console.log("dblclick");
  card.classList.toggle("large");
});
card.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  // solution with e.detail corresponding to click.count
  if (e.detail === 1) {
    console.log(`click count is: ${e.detail}`);
  } else if (e.detail > 1) {
    console.log(`click count is: ${e.detail}, probably a double click is happening`);
  }
});
```

```css
aside {
  background: #fe9;
  border-radius: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
  transform: scale(0.9);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  user-select: none;
}

.large {
  transform: scale(1.3);
}
```

```html
<aside>
  <h3>My Card</h3>
  <p>Double click to resize this object.</p>
</aside>
```

[Edit] What the event `dlbclick` has that you could implements:

- There is location limit between the first click and the second one, if the second click is far from 15px it doesn't count as a double click ([Chromium gesture configuration](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/9d749ecf1848391b911f889e03065a3021a88cb9/ui/events/gesture_detection/gesture_configuration.h#L247));
- The timing is most likely in the native event 700ms ([Chromium gesture configuration](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/9d749ecf1848391b911f889e03065a3021a88cb9/ui/events/gesture_detection/gesture_configuration.h#L244));
- With native event you can click and do a "long press" to double click within 800ms ([Chromium gesture configuration](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/9d749ecf1848391b911f889e03065a3021a88cb9/ui/events/gesture_detection/gesture_configuration.h#L245C7-L245C47));
- Timing handling uses timestamps comparison and no timeouts ([Chromium event](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/9d749ecf1848391b911f889e03065a3021a88cb9/ui/events/event.cc#L511-L513)).

Comment: Perhaps also add the "click" event handler since the OP has both in use.

Comment: 'Full support on most browsers since Dec. 22, 2023.' : Is it really that new? Anyway, doesn't really help, see this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/exbuyka2/1/ - I will edit / extend my question.

Comment: References have a list of which version of which browser - not super new probably for many of them.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using native `dblclick` event ([MDN dblclick event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/dblclick_event))?

```js
let click = document.getElementById("click");

function clickMe() {
  click.innerHTML = "single click";
}

function doubleClick() {
  click.innerHTML = "double click";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="clickMe()" ondblclick="doubleClick()">
  Click me
</button>
<p id="click"></p>
```

Comment: The single click fires twice before the double click. JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/exbuyka2/1/- Perhaps I oversimlified my problem - I will edit my question to suit.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, one possible solution can be to use Promises.

Here is an example.

```
let clickTimer;
let clickPromiseResolver;

const clickDelay = 200;

function handleSingleOrDoubleClick() {
  if (clickPromiseResolver) {
    clickPromiseResolver.reject({ doubleClick: true });
    clickPromiseResolver = null;
  } else {
    const clickPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      clickPromiseResolver = { resolve, reject };
      clickTimer = setTimeout(() => {
        resolve({ singleClick: true });
      }, clickDelay);
    });

    clickPromise.then((clickType) => {
      if (clickType.singleClick) {
        singleClickAction();
      }
    }).catch((reason) => {
      if (reason.doubleClick) {
        doubleClickAction();
      }
    }).finally(() => {
      clearTimeout(clickTimer);
      clickTimer = null;
      clickPromiseResolver = null;
    });
  }
}

function singleClickAction() {
  console.log('Single click action');
}

function doubleClickAction() {
  console.log('Double click action');
}

document.addEventListener('click', () => {
  handleSingleOrDoubleClick();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I tried  this, although I had to remove the `catch`/`finally` to make it work at all. It still suffers from the original problem, i.e. a slow dblclick leads to two singles (or , with a longer timeout, the response to a single click is too slow. Demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/aq6ftcej/1/

Comment: Hmm, I'm trying to understand what's the problem ? If you need to handle the slow double click, you can increase the 200ms delay.

Comment: @quilkin btw, I've updated the code, now it should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I have decided that there is no satisfactory answer to this problem. I am not using jquery, but those docs say:

> It is inadvisable to bind handlers to both the click and dblclick events for the same element. The sequence of events triggered varies from browser to browser, with some receiving two click events before the dblclick and others only one. Double-click sensitivity (maximum time between clicks that is detected as a double click) can vary by operating system and browser, and is often user-configurable.

If the designers of jquery can't make it work consistently than I doubt that I can!

I have revisited my design and decided that I can use two different elements to activate the different clicks (for the record, I wanted a single click to make a 'wheel' rotate forwards a little, a double-click to make it go backwards. I have now added extra elements to the wheel circumference with subtle colour differences and a slightly different cursor for each direction.)