# kineticjs - click event is also fired on dblclick

Tags: kineticjs

I am working with "dblclick" event and if I register a click and dblclick event for a shape, click event is called twice before calling the dblclick event code. This behaviour is making my code go crazy. Since I have some actions for click and different set of actions for dblclick. I am not sure whether this is a bug in kineticjs or this is a expected behaviour. I need help incase of handling this probelm. I need to help in making dblclick to work without calling the click event. Kindly suggest.

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle link explaining the programhttp://jsfiddle.net/fc6xE/

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is not a Kinetic issue, but just DOM events in general.

[Prevent click event from firing when dblclick event fires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880608/prevent-click-event-from-firing-when-dblclick-event-fires)