# What is the max delay between two clicks to trigger a double-click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

What is the maximum delay between two clicks that will still trigger a double-click event?  Does this delay change between plain JavaScript, jquery, and AngularJS?

Similarly, in jquery what timings do the fast and slow keywords correspond to?  For example, I can use either `$(this).hide("slow");` or `$(this).hide("fast");`.  Is there a way to change the default values for fast and slow?

Comment: From the [doc](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) _The strings `fast` and `slow` can be supplied to indicate durations of 200 and 600 milliseconds, respectively._

Comment: I would assume "double click" to be handled by the OS on the client, not the scripting language. But I'm just guessing

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The maximum delay required for two consecutive clicks to be interpreted as a double-click is not standardized.

Generally the events are fired by the browser, and the browser again uses whatever is set in the OS.
According to Microsoft, the default timing in Windows is 500ms (one half second), other operating systems can have other delays, and most have settings that can be changed by the user.

For jQuery, it's in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/), the values for the animation speed is as follows

fast   : 200
normal : 400
slow   : 600

Answer (score 1):

The strings 'fast' and 'slow' is supplied to indicate durations of 200 and 600 milliseconds