# Triple click as events on React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, click, interaction

### Triple Clicks

When I’m in the development phase of a project, I like to tweak forms to fill in all fields with one **triple click event** over one another element (div or header usually), just to avoid filling all the individual inputs by hand one by one. I choose triple clicks because it’s more difficult to perform them by users by error.

### React Events

In Javascript we can attach custom events over the React components on the application, as we have the `onClick` event and the `onDoubleClick` event, but i can't realize how to make with more clicks. In other words, how to emulate the `onTripleClick()` event.

### Sample Code

```
render() {
    return (
        <FormComponent>

            <FormHeader
                onClick={this.doWhatever}
                onDoubleClick={this.doMore}
                onTripleClick={this.fillFormWithSampleData}
            >
                Create Promotion
            </FormHeader>

            {/* ... */}
            {/* ... */}
            {/* ... */}

            {/* Tons of things here */}

        </FormComponent>
    );
}
```

I was wondering if someone knows if there’s a native way to deal with this in React, as I don’t want to use third party libraries nor jQuery. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just check event detail:

```
class Test extends React.Component{
    onClick(e){
        console.log(e.detail === 3? "tripple click" : "not tripple click");
    }
    render(){
        return <div onClick={this.onClick}>click</div>;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew! That's a perfect solucion. Clean, simple, and inside event object.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: And, of course, you can accept as the right answer, if you think so.

Comment: Hi Andrew. I'm completely new in Stack Overflow, sorry. Yes, this is the correct one, just that I didn't know that i have to accept it. Doing... Thanks for the info!

Comment: When I do this it registers as three separate click events, each with a detail of 1.

Comment: @NeilGirardi I think your problem is about this https://stackoverflow.com/a/29917394/7132340.
I tried this https://jsfiddle.net/5te4u7g3/, it works for me in Google Chrome / Mac OS.

Comment: Beware that this does not work with (you guessed it) Internet Explorer: https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_uievent_detail

Comment: This won't work on mobile browsers (tested on iPhone's Safari and Chrome)

Answer (score 2):

this is not an issue related to react, You can do it with javascript in general.
You can listen to a 1 click event and check the event's details object (number of clicks followed).
Example:

```js
var trippleEl = document.getElementById('tripple');
trippleEl.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (e.detail === 3) {
        console.log('3 times a charm');
    }
});
```

```html
<h1 id="tripple">hi there</h1>
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. I mixed concepts. Thanks for pointing it. Editing.

Comment: Your answer it's also correct, of course. But i have to choose only one!. Thanks to you also ;)