# Does multiple concurrent setInterval() affect performance?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance

I am building a todo app where in each todo the user submits, the user is allowed to edit that todo later if he/she wants. I want the todo to be editable only when the todo is tapped twice under 600ms. Failing to find any other solutions to this problem, I stumbled upon the below given solution.

```
    const [tappedOnce, setTappedOnce] = React.useState(false)

    const onTap = () => {
        if (tappedOnce) {
            setEditable(true)
            setTimeout(() => todoRef.current.focus())
            setTappedOnce(false)

        } else setTappedOnce(true)
    }

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const intId = setInterval(() => {
            setTappedOnce(false)
        }, 600)

        return () => clearInterval(intId)
    }, [])
```

In the solution, I am resetting the `tappedOnce` state value to false every 600ms. But as you can probably guess, if the user has 50 todos, then I will have 50 concurrent `setInterval` processes running at the same time. Is this going to affect the performance of the app by any significant margin? Are there  any better solution to this problem?

Comment: There's no need for the setInterval is there? You can setTimeout(() => setTappedOnce(false),600) inside the onTap function.

Comment: If I do that then it no longer cares about the duration between the two taps, it just works after 2 consecutive taps, not necessarily after 600ms. The second tap can occur after 10s and even then it will work, which is not desired.

Comment: Besides, I would still like to know the performance impact of multiple concurrent setInterval().

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48835180/2822041

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial `setTimeout(setTappedOnce, 600, false);` You don't even need that arrow function

Comment: just a habit. .

Answer (score 1):

here an alternative approach, using just a ref to store the moment of the last click/tap/whatever

```
const lastClick = useRef(NaN);

const onTap = event => {
  const timeStamp = event.timeStamp; // or Date.now()
  if (timeStamp - lastClick.current < 600) {
    lastClick.current = NaN;
    setTimeout(() => todoRef.current.focus());
  } else {
    lastClick.current = timeStamp;
  }
}
```

Comment: why `useRef()` and not `useState()`?

Comment: because I don't need/want to rerender when the user clicked once. Maybe not even when he clicked twice, like in this case; we don't need to rerender to set the focus. Imo. `useRef` is the best option of a "state without rerender". I'd use a state when that state affects the view.

Comment: And `lastClick.current` is synchronous, it will always hold the latest value. Even if I memoize `onTap`. I don't need to worry/handle that I might deal with a closure over an outdated state.

Comment: why not just use store `lastClick` on a plain variable if state doesn't matter?

Answer (score 0):

YES! Multiple concurrent setInterval() does affect performance. If they are not cleared they will just continue running, and it's a hassle keeping track of id's to clear if you have other intervals.

You could use a timeout instead.
Whenever you click you set `recentClick = true`
Then you use a setTimeout(b) to make `recentClick = false` after the 600ms.