# Separate action for single click and double click with RxJs

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

**I have a problem with RxJs.**

I need to log a message in console.log when I click once, and different message when I click twice on the button. The problems are:

- at the beginning if I click first time - nothing happens - wrong 
  (I should see first message 'one click')
- then if I click on the button and then (after one second) I click again, for the second click I can see two messages - wrong (I should see only one message per action)
- when I click on the button, wait a second, click again, wait a second and click again, then for the last click I will see three messages in console.log - wrong (I should see only one message per action)
- after that if I click twice (doubleclick) I will see five messages for double click, and one for one click - wrong (I should see only one message 'double click')

all I want is:

- if I click once, I need to see only one message ('one click')
- if I click twice (doubleclick), still I need to see only one message ('double click')
- if I click more than twice - nothing happens

any help?

[check hear for examples](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cfkt7c)

Comment: please put your code in your question as well

Comment: yeah I forget, thx

Comment: have you tried angulars (dblclick) binding instead of a complex observable?

Comment: of course, but I need another solution for ios where dblclick is not working properly

Comment: FYI, the reason you're getting multiples of each message is because you are resubscribing to the observable every time the `test()` function is called. You should unsubscribe after the observable subscription callback fires. Which begs the question, why are you using observables in the first place? Seems like a regular click handler should do, yeah?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very simple answer (not using any observables) is to use a `setTimeout()` and check on each click if the timeout is already set, if so, you know it's a second click within a given time window (double click) and if not, it's the first click. If the timeout expires, you know it was just a single click, like so:

[Updated StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rpzixp)

```
// have a timer that will persist between function calls
private clickTimeout = null;
public test(event): void {
  // if timeout exists, we know it's a second click within the timeout duration
  // AKA double click
  if (this.clickTimeout) {
    // first, clear the timeout to stop it from completing
    clearTimeout(this.clickTimeout);
    // set to null to reset
    this.clickTimeout = null;
    // do whatever you want on double click
    console.log("double!");
  } else {
  // if timeout doesn't exist, we know it's first click
    this.clickTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      // if timeout expires, we know second click was not handled within time window
      // so we can treat it as a single click
      // first, reset the timeout
      this.clickTimeout = null;
      // do whatever you want on single click
      console.log("one click");
    }, 400);
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

I missed the part about ignoring any more than 2 clicks. It's not that much more work, but I broke it out a bit more to be able to reuse code, so it looks like a lot more. Anyway, to ignore 3+ clicks, it would look like the following:

```
// count the clicks
private clicks = 0;
private clickTimeout = null;
public test(event): void {
  this.clicks++;
  if (this.clickTimeout) {
    // if is double click, set the timeout to handle double click
    if (this.clicks <= 2) {
      this.setClickTimeout(this.handleDoubleClick);
    } else {
    // otherwise, we are at 3+ clicks, use an empty callback to essentially do a "no op" when completed
      this.setClickTimeout(() => {});
    }
  } else {
    // if timeout doesn't exist, we know it's first click - treat as single click until further notice
    this.setClickTimeout(this.handleSingleClick);
  }
}
// sets the click timeout and takes a callback for what operations you want to complete when the
// click timeout completes
public setClickTimeout(cb) {
  // clear any existing timeout
  clearTimeout(this.clickTimeout);
  this.clickTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
    this.clickTimeout = null;
    this.clicks = 0;
    cb();
  }, 400);
}
public handleSingleClick() {
  console.log("one click");
}
public handleDoubleClick() {
  console.log("double!");
}
```

Comment: @Przemo Is there a specific reason you *need* to use Rxjs? I didn't get that out of the original question. I thought you were trying to solve the problem with Rxjs, not that it was a requirement. Can you edit your question shed some more light on your requirements?

Comment: I decided to use your solution. Thx!

Comment: @Przemo Great =) Glad it worked for you. Please be sure to mark the answer as accepted for future viewers. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

@Siddharth Ajmeras answer shows how to do this with events. I was not aware a dblclick event existed. The more you know. If you are still interested on how to do this with rxjs, here is an example.

```
// How fast does the user has to click
// so that it counts as double click
const doubleClickDuration = 100;

// Create a stream out of the mouse click event.
const leftClick$ = fromEvent(window, 'click')
// We are only interested in left clicks, so we filter the result down
  .pipe(filter((event: any) => event.button === 0));

// We have two things to consider in order to detect single or
// or double clicks.

// 1. We debounce the event. The event will only be forwared 
// once enough time has passed to be sure we only have a single click
const debounce$ = leftClick$
  .pipe(debounceTime(doubleClickDuration));

// 2. We also want to abort once two clicks have come in.
const clickLimit$ = leftClick$
  .pipe(
    bufferCount(2),
  );


// Now we combine those two. The gate will emit once we have 
// either waited enough to be sure its a single click or
// two clicks have passed throug
const bufferGate$ = race(debounce$, clickLimit$)
  .pipe(
    // We are only interested in the first event. After that
    // we want to restart.
    first(),
    repeat(),
  );

// Now we can buffer the original click stream until our
// buffer gate triggers.
leftClick$
  .pipe(
    buffer(bufferGate$),
    // Here we map the buffered events into the length of the buffer
    // If the user clicked once, the buffer is 1. If he clicked twice it is 2
    map(clicks => clicks.length),
  ).subscribe(clicks => console.log('CLicks', clicks));
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer: reactive, pure, composable into other observable pipelines. Great job!

Answer (score 0):

This is either what you want or very close to it:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})

export class AppComponent  {

  @ViewChild('mybutton') button: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    fromEvent(this.button.nativeElement, 'dblclick')
    .subscribe(e => console.log('double click'));

    fromEvent(this.button.nativeElement, 'click')
    .subscribe((e: MouseEvent) => {
      if (e.detail === 1) console.log('one click') // could use a filter inside a pipe instead of using an if statement
      // if (e.detail === 2) console.log('double click') // an alternative for handling double clicks
    });
  }
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<button #mybutton>Test</button>
```

This solution uses event.detail and is loosely based on this useful post - [Prevent click event from firing when dblclick event fires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880608/prevent-click-event-from-firing-when-dblclick-event-fires) - which not only discusses event.detail but also looks at the timing issues involved.

One of the big probs with your code is that you are subscribing to the event inside a function that is called multiple times, which means each time the button is clicked you create another subscription. Using `ngAfterViewInit` (which is only called once as part of the lifecycle) prevents this issue (and ensures the DOM is loaded).

Here's a stackblitz for you:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t6cvjj

Forgive me for my sloppy type declarations!

This satisfies your requirements as follows:

- If I click once, I need to see only one message ('one click') - PASS
- If I click twice (doubleclick), still I need to see only one message ('double click') - FAIL, you see 'one click' on the 1st click and 'double click' on the 2nd click
- If I click more than twice - nothing happens - PASS

Due to the timing issues discussed in the SO post given, how you solve this is a matter of preference and thus I decided not to tackle it. And plus, you are not paying me ;) This answer however should set you well on your way to solving it fully.

PS There is a comment on the SO post above that suggests event.detail may not work on IE11

Comment: OP said that dblclick event is not working properly on IOS. Not sure if this will work